# Prompt to chose mapreduce action

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce, jobs

I completed two mapreduce jobs using python mapper and reducer (the one calculates the average rating per movie and the other the average rating per user)

The project needs me to give the user at runtime, the option to choose between the two jobs.

How could I do that?

Comment: How about a Bash script that takes a user's input to run one of the two separate commands?